# How to force image to take all available height given by container

Tags: html, css, image

I have an two `<image />`s and a `<p/>`, each wrapped in a `<span />` which are again childs of a `<div />`. Both images have different dimensions. I need them to always take half of the available width (which works) and then scale them up to 100% of the available height. The latter does not work.

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 100%;
    column-gap: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.image-caption-wrapper {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
}

.image {
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    height: 100%;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  <div class="container">
    <span class="image-caption-wrapper">
      <img class="image" src="https://dummyimage.com/800x200/000/fff"/>
      <p>Some Image Caption</p>
    </span>
    <span class="image-caption-wrapper">
      <img class="image" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff"/>
      <p>Some Other Image Caption</p>
    </span>
  </div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
```

Why is the `800 x 200` image not taking all the available height, eventhough the height of it is set to 100%?

Comment: You been here for almost nine years and you have > 10k rep - and you still don't know that a proper [mre] of your issue belongs _directly_ into your question, and not just dumped onto an external platform?

Comment: @CBroe forgot about that. Tried to replicate in the fiddle, couldnt explain the behaviour and then just copy and pasted the link here without thinking. I included the example in the Q now.

Comment: With a fixed container height this should work.

Comment: A `<p>` is a block content not phrasing content and thus not permitted inside a `span` ref: Span is an inline element which can not contain block elements. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span

Comment: FWIW since you are removing the margin from the `p` element why even use that? I would suggest changing the containing `span` to a `div` as well as the `p` as I would consider these "syntax" issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to give height to main block (.container) , because children blocks
cant understand what 100% they need to fill .

Answer (score 0):

#### Hello there,

- I understand your problem "*Why is the `800 x 200` image not taking all the available height, eventhough the height of it is set to `100%`?*". So let me explain how you can rectify that problem.

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 100%;
    column-gap: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.image-caption-wrapper {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

- Your code consists of `flex` layout, but if you want to span the both image elements as you said then you need to use `grid` layout

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 10px;
  margin: 50px 0;
}

.image-caption-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

- The above code helps us to efficiently place the images as you said and we removed the `width: 100%`, because `div` is a block level element so it automatically occupies `100%` of `width` by default.
- And we used `margin` of `50px` for both top and bottom along with changing the width of `.image-caption-wrapper` to `100%` so that our both images will occupy entire space

**I hope you find this feedback helpful !**

Comment: Yes and no. If you remove the `margin: 50px 0;`, there is a weird behaviour. The bottom text overlays the caption text... Why is the text overlaying the `<span class="image-caption-wrapper">` respectivly `<div class="container">`?

Comment: Yeah that happens because of setting the `width` and `height` of `.image-caption-wrapper` to `100%`,

You want to note that we used `display: grid` for `container` and `.image-caption-wrapper` is the child of `container`.

The `img` element occupies the entire available `width` and `height` from `.image-caption-wrapper` so that the `p` is pushed down.

So we added `margin: 50px 0` to balance the layout.